# How to cleanup async tasks created outside useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I created a custom hook `useFetch` that returns a `fetch` function that I can use in other components. It uses a promise to fetch some data inside. My goal is to clean up the pending promise, if the component, that uses this custom hook gets unmounted.

How would I do it? I tried something using `useRef`, but without success yet. Still getting the `Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.` warning.

```
const useFetch = (url) => {
  const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(false)
  const handler = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => () => {
    if (handler.current !== null) {
      handler.current.cancel()
    }
  }, [])

  return (options) => {
    handler.current = window.fetch(url, options)
    setIsFetching(true)

    return handler.current.then(() => {
      handler.current = null
      setIsFetching(false)
    })
  }
}

export default () => {
  const fetchData = useFetch('www.tld')

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData({}).then(() => console.log('done'))
  }, [])

  return null
}
```

Notice that the promise in this example is cancelable via `.cancel()` (so thats not a problem here).

Comment: What should the code do? What does it do instead? What isn't working? "It doesn't work" isn't a good problem description :)

Comment: Do you use request-promise ?

Comment: Why does it matter? And nope. :D

Comment: because [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) doesn't returns a promise and requires callbacks

Comment: I'm using regular fetch.

Answer (score 0):

Return `cancel()` as bound callback from your hook. Then it would be up to consumer to stop it:

```
const useFetch(url) {
  const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(false)
  const handler = useRef(null)

  function run(options) {
    handler.current = window.fetch(url, options)
    setIsFetching(true)
    ...
  }
  function cancel() {
    if(handler.current) {
      handler.current.cancel()
    }
  }

  return {run, cancel}
}

...
function OtherComponent({userId}) {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);

  const {run, cancel} = useFetch(`/user/${userId}`);

  useEffect(() => {
    run(options).then(setUserData);

    return cancel; // it's up to consumer code to stop request
  }, [userId]); 
}
```

Comment: Hm, that seems promising. Will try that on monday, thank you!